# Is there any other meaning of "I" except I?

Tags: meaning-in-context

curious on the meaning of  "I" , anything more than I?

Comment: I can't decide whether "I" is the entity *writing* this comment, or the entity ***watching*** [someone else?] write it. But I think that's what philosophers call [the hard question of consciousness.](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rstb.2017.0342)

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. If you look up *I* in any dictionary, the various things *I* can represent will be spelled out. As a reminder, questions at Stack Exchange are expected to demonstrate some initial attempts at research. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

On the topic of English Learners, no... I only use "I" to refer to myself.

There are a few other things you might see, but the only common one is the ordered list:

I. Go to the grocery store

II. Pay the light bill

III. Put gas in car

IV. Call Mom for recipe

V. Put dinner in slow cooker

... those are Roman numerals and represent 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 (four can be written "IIII" instead of "IV"; "IV" is more common)

Comment: Also, *I* is the symbol for the element iodine, and *I* can be used in various equations to denote [current](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-ohm.htm) or simple interest (*I = Prt*). But these are niche uses.

Comment: True, and it can be used to denote a unit vector parallel to the x-axis.